# Bind Skrollr Animations to Div Scroll Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, skrollr

Is it possible to bind Skrollr animations to an inner div's scroll bar and not the main window scroll bar?

I have a div on the page that contains all Skrollr content. This div's overflow is set to scroll thus has a scrollbar. As the user scrolls down this div I want to play the Skrollr animations/keyframes and not play any animations as the user scrolls the page.

Is such a thing possible?